# ¿Cómo hacer una notificación tipo facebook en EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, cshtml

después de mucho buscar vengo a ustedes para solicitar ayuda.

Para poner en contexto estoy desarrollando una aplicación MVC con EntityFramework, todo lo que contiene es solo con lo que se carga el proyecto autogenerado con Visual Studio 2022.

Con esto como punto de partida lo que deseo realizar es una forma de mostrar determinado numero como una notificación como las de publicaciones de facebook, por ejemplo digamos que tengo el modelo llamado "**Personas**"
lo hago en el controlador "**HomeControlle**" es:

```
public ActionResult Contar()
{
    ViewData["Contar"] = ctx.Personas.Count(); //ctx es el context del dbcontext
    return View();
}
```

Ahora viene la parte "interesante", esta notificación quiero que este en el layout, no puedo usar @model pues no pueden coexistir 2 modelos en una vista (esto porque existirán otros modelos), entonces lo que pongo es:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li> 
        <a>
           Personas
           <span>@ViewData["Contar"]</span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

Obviamente esta solución solo perdurara por el request y en el mejor de los casos de los que conozco y he implementado mientras no cambie de controlador, esto no es conveniente pues el usuario puede que no atienda de inmediato esa notificación, pero lo ideal es que perdure, como cuando uno recibe notificaciones de facebook.

Comment: no podes usar dos model.. pero si podes generar un viewmodel que contenga varios model ;)... si no, todo el mundo tendria muchos problemas con muchas pantallas....

Comment: Se que no puedo usar dos modelos como comente en la linea antes del código del _Layout, es por ello que como dije lo que uso mientras en ViewData, pero que esta opción en el mejor de los casos solo perdura hasta que salga del controlador, yo estoy tratando de que el contador sea un dato que perdure, no que al cambiar de vista este desaparezca.

Comment: Te doy una idea: investiga sobre Websocket, es la forma en que Facebook notifica. La manera antigua, utilizar una petición Ajax cada xx tiempo que obtenga el dato a actualizar en la vista.